# Detect below string using regex in uima RUTA

Tags: regex, regex-greedy, uima, uimanageddocument, ruta

I'm trying to annotate below string as a type using regex in **UIMA RUTA**.

> SAMPLE:

- *******$10.00*

> Other Variant:

- *******$10.00***
- *******$90.00*
- *******$99**

  Regex: *+\$\d+.\d+*+

**UIMA REGEX:**

```
SPECIAL{REGEXP("\\*+\\$\\d+.\\d+\\*+") -> MARK(AmC,1)};
```

I'm not able to detect as * represent greedy regex but as I'm using escape character() still something is missing.Any workaround?

> **PS: It's working for other regex engine but not working in UIMA RUTA**

Comment: You forgot to double escape the final backslash before the asterisk (assuming that you need to double escape).  Also, perhaps you need boundary markers?

Comment: `SPECIAL{REGEXP(".*\\*+\\$\\d+\\.\\d+\\*+.*") -> MARK(AmC,1)};` ???

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's working when I tested on regex101.com but not working in UIMA RUTA.

Comment: This won't work since the condition is only applied on the covered text of the matched annotation, which represents only a part of the required string.

Comment: @PeterKluegl but as I'm Plus Greedy it should annotate.

Comment: It's the other way around: the regex won't see enough text in order to match completely. I'll add an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REGEXP condition applies Java Pattern `matches()` on the covered text of the matched annotation of the rule element. In your example, this is `SPECIAL` which is a single special character. Thus, the regex tried to match on a single "*" and then anew the next character (excluding the digit and the period).

The REGEXP condition is not really suitable here. You should rather use a simple regex rule like:

```
"\\*+\\$\\d+.\\d+\\*+" -> AmC;
```

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: Work like a charm. Thanks a lot for such brilliant explanation.